# How do I copy page elements from a website into python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website to find the holder addresses of a certain token. When I select the address and inspect the page I am brought to the elements section. It is formatted in html so I assumed that is where I could scrape it from.

I tried this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# opening and grabbing html

holders_text = requests.get("https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokenholders2?a=0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37&sid=&m=normal&s=3863&p=1").text
holders_html = BeautifulSoup(holders_text, 'lxml')

print(holders_html)
```

But I quickly found that this html was quite different than what I am looking for.

I am trying to figure out whether there is a way to extract the page elements into python, specifically each address as shown here:

[Picture of what I am trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPqF1.png)

If there is any way to scrape for this data please let me know, thank you!

Also here is the website url: https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokenholders2?a=0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37&sid=&m=normal&s=3863&p=1

Comment: Wouldn't `driver.page_source` return the non-evaluated raw HTML source of the page? Is the data you're after dynamically generated using JavaScript? If so, it would never be present in `driver.page_source`. What exactly is `"stuff"` that you're looking for? Why not use a specific selector combination to retrieve the data you're after? The method you've chosen here really isn't best practice, per se. "*Basically I am wondering how I can make sure to get ALL of the source code from the url.*" ALL of the source code to a page should be in `driver.page_source`; is it not?

Comment: Driver.page_source appears to return a truncated version of the source code I see. The "stuff" is simply a long class definition that occurs multiple times. It must be dynamically generated I guess, is there any way to view this?

Comment: Can you share an example of a publicly-accessible site that exhibits this behavior (where `driver.page_source` returns a truncated source code?

Comment: Your question still significantly lacks specifics required to answer this question concretely. "*The "stuff" is simply a long class definition that occurs multiple times.*" A JavaScript class definition? A CSS class definition? Can you be more specific? What do you want to do with it? Simply print a message when the class is defined in the current page? "*It must be dynamically generated I guess, is there any way to view this?*" What is "*it*"? The class definition? On what conditions does it appear to be dynamically generated? What would you, in your own words, constitute as "*viewing [it]*"?

Comment: Yes of course, the page I am looking at is an Etherscan, for example: https://etherscan.io/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37#balances

Comment: I want to look at the addresses of the holders, so I was simply parsing the html for specific addresses, which appeared in the source code. I am not doing this for any utility, but rather to check if ALL of the source code is there. (eventually my goal is to save these addresses into a list)

Comment: The return value of `driver.page_source` matches near exactly to the source code my browser retrieves from the remote server normally. Can you clarify if you're talking about the DOM or the page source? They are two completely different things. If it's the former - you should really consider answering the questions I posited in my last comment. Why not just target the data you require using the appropriate DOM selectors? Wouldn't that be much easier? Your question still severely lacks the necessary specificity to be answerable.

Comment: As I stated above, I am trying to find the specific addresses of the holders. If you select an address and right click it, then inspect it, THAT is what I am trying to create a list of. I am not sure what that would be considered, as I am not very experienced in HTML or web design. I also do not know what DOM selectors are, if that would be easier for my case, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding your problem here.

Your website https://etherscan.io/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37#balances
generates your target (the `Holders` tab) dynamically.

If you open a web inspector of your borwser and click on page 2 you'll see a data request being made by javascript:

[image]

Here you can see the actual data url of your target:

https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokenholders2?a=0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37&sid=&m=normal&s=3863&p=2

Take a look at parameters: `a` is for address name and `p` is page
To get these addresses all you need to do is scrape this url instead of the whole page.

You don't even need Selenium or webdriver!
Here's your scraper with `python` with `requests` and `parsel` packages:

```py
from parsel import Selector
import requests
response = requests.get("https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokenholders2?a=0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37&sid=&m=normal&s=3863&p=2", headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"})
sel = Selector(response.text)
sel.css("tr>td>a::attr(href)").extract()
['/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0x2643796cb6b4e715140f09c352ea26afff1a7d93', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0x69bab6810fa99475854bca0a3dd72ae6a0728ece', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0xf9f56b6dc4c297b0d942b0e03f7e67d6dd0ed7be', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0x5aeedbc6b655c13950f32e5e8a0760d15bbe0afb', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0x00084121aec4309cb20db622a28c717720e888e0', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0xdfc70f5205a2bc1bd44219fd852d720d7a36c5b8', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0x6f35b0cfc58eb1e21eef8a439bbb0ce4c929d32a', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0xfa6023f9c140c6ec5c78d19b91d4bdece8de107d', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0x2f5db226b29abfd1aa01f53e4ea3493b6e69c050', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0x9ffad2ff3a59d8579e3b0edc6c8f2f591c94dfab', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0xb1c51fbecee5a397177c934b76acd080c105d648', '/token/0x57a204aa1042f6e66dd7730813f4024114d74f37?a=0x8cbc7327b5fe2bce2c69fdafd58aeae83d349eb2']
```

Comment: That helps so much, thank you! However, when I inspect the url you provided, the html still does not give me the addresses. The address in the url is the NFT that is being held, while the addresses in the list are the holders. I would like to dynamically scrape these addresses from the list, along with their hyperlinks ideally. Is this possible?

Comment: I also updated my question so hopefully it is a bit more clear, thank you again for your help!