# Scrape info from a webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have combed this site and have tried several approaches to no avail. I'm trying to scrape the top holder percentage and wallet address of a token from bscscan.com (see attached pic). Here are my attempts. Bscscan API would have put me out of my misery if the endpoint with this info wasn't a premium service. Also if you know a less painful way to obtain this info please don't hold back. Pls advise on any of the methods below, thanks in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from lxml import etree

token = "0x7754c0584372D29510C019136220f91e25a8f706"
url = f"https://bscscan.com/token/{token}#balances"

#First attempt
webpage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
d = etree.HTML(str(soup))
print(d.xpath('//*[@id="maintable"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/text()'))
print(d.xpath('//*[@id="maintable"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/a'))


#Second attempt
from lxml import etree
holding = etree.parse(url, etree.HTMLParser())
holding.xpath('//[@id="maintable"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/text()')
print(holding)


#Third attempt
for tr in soup.find_all('<td>1</td>'):
    tds = tr.find_all('_parent')
    tds.get_text()
    print(tds)


#Fourth attempt
from parsel import Selector
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get("https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokenholders2?m=normal&a=0x7754c0584372D29510C019136220f91e25a8f706&s=100000000000000000000000000&sid=066c697ef6a537ed95ccec0084a464ec&p=1", headers) 

sel = Selector(response.text)
address = sel.css("tr>td>a::attr(_parent)").extract()
percentage = sel.css("tr>td[3]").extract()
print(address)
print( percentage)
```

[image]

Comment: A few minutes looking at the page source would have told you that the chart is entirely built by Javascript.  Those  numbers are not present in the HTML.  You will have to use something like Selenium to have the Javascript executed.

Comment: @TimRoberts That makes sense, so it's dynamically generated then. Could you show me how to pull those two pieces of info out with Selenium?

Comment: You don't need to use browser emulation. See my related answer here for https://etherscan.io which works almost the same way your website does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69445336/3737009

Comment: @Granitosaurus Wow, that's way cleaner than I was expecting. So I have applied it to my website (Question updated: See Fourth attempt) but it returns an empty set could you pls check it out to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your issue resolved? @BJonas88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 4th attempt is very close! What you should do instead is iterate through each row and extract data based on column numbers:

```py
for row in sel.css('tr'):
    # percentage is on 5th column
    perc = row.xpath('td[4]/text()').get()
    if not perc:  # skip rows with no percentage info
        continue
    # addres is on 2nd column under <a> node
    # we can also use `re()` method to only take the token part of the url
    addr = row.xpath('td[1]//a/@href').re('/token/([^#?]+)')[0]
    print(addr, perc)
```

which results in:

```
0x7754c0584372D29510C019136220f91e25a8f706 54.9648% 
0x7754c0584372D29510C019136220f91e25a8f706 16.8033% 
0x7754c0584372D29510C019136220f91e25a8f706 9.0000% 
0x7754c0584372D29510C019136220f91e25a8f706 7.6600% 
0x7754c0584372D29510C019136220f91e25a8f706 1.2000% 
...
```

Also noticed there's a slight typo in your request line:

```
response = requests.get("...", headers)
                               ^^^^^^^
# this part should be keyword argument
response = requests.get("...", headers=headers)
```

Comment: Sweeeet! Thanks a bunch. Corrected "headers=headers" and I also changed td[1] to td[2] and it worked! One final request (forgive me if I'm asking too much). My result shows up as such...  e.g.  "0x7754c0584372D29510C019136220f91e25a8f706?a=0xf6383d92749c590fae591002f2c978ca03cdb471 54.9648%". I just need the latter part for addr ("0xf6383d92749c590fae591002f2c978ca03cdb471"). When inspect the address I notice it's standing alone in the path 'td[2]]//a/@target/' after '_parent/'. What do I need to change in the path to get to it?

Comment: @BJonas88 seems like the bit you want is also present in the text of the node (text of node in xml is everything between the `<>` tags, e.g. `<node>this is text</node>`). For that try using the text selector. In `xpath` that would be `text()` command, as in: `td[2]//a/text()`.

Comment: Ok I see, that would do it. Thanks again

Comment: pls save me again lol https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718690/scrape-data-from-a-dynamic-web-table-using-parsel-selector